# How to check response returned from tabwriter.Writer in golang

Tags: go

I am writting something to tabwriter.Writer object,

```
    w := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 5, 1, 3, ' ', 0)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\t%v\t\n", somevalue1, somevalue2)
```

I can print the data in w in console using w.Flush()
Is there any way so get values in w as string in one place and compare it with some value?

I want to compare what I have in w with some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own `io.Writer`:

```
type W []byte

func (w *W) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    *w = append(*w, b...)
    return len(b), nil
}
```

You can then pass an instance of `*W` to `tabwriter.NewWriter`:

```
sw := &W{}
w := tabwriter.NewWriter(sw, 5, 1, 3, ' ', 0)
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\t%v\t\n", somevalue1, somevalue2)

// get the string value from sw
str := string(*sw)
```

As sugested by @Tim, you should use `*bytes.Buffer` instead for better performance and it already implements `io.Writer`:

```
var b bytes.Buffer
w := tabwriter.NewWriter(&b, 0, 0, 1, '.', 0)
// ...
fmt.Println(b.String())
```

Comment: I would recommend just using `bytes.Buffer` instead of implementing that method myself.

Comment: Don't forget w.Flush() like me.